# Harvesting Resources in Civ6

Tags: civilization-6

I'm probably missing something here -- or missed a in game tip -- but how do you harvest strategic resource?

For example, I want the [Niter](http://civ6.gamepedia.com/Niter) in my region. I own the tile and I'm working it. I have a farm improvement on the tile.

I completed the research to [Gunpowder](http://civ6.gamepedia.com/Gunpowder) several turns ago (which revealed the deposit).

Despite the above, I see no indication of access to the resource and I can't figure out what improvement I might need to build (if any) to get it. So, how do I harvest this strategic resource and more broadly, how does this system work in Civ6. In civ5, this all seemed automatic... It makes me wonder if there is a bug or something...

Comment: A farm doesn't produce niter. You'll need to turn it into a mine.

Comment: Aside: "Harvesting" is a builder action that removes the resource from the map in exchange for a one-time boost in yields (sort of like chopping does for forests).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to get the Niter resource you'll need to remove the farm and build a mine instead.

Different resources(luxury or strategic) need different improvements. For example, to gain sheep you'll need to build a pasture on that tile, to get oil you'll need to build an oil rig, etc.. When your worker is on the tile that has a resource, it'll usually recommend the improvement for you.

Comment: Fair enough for the Niter but the larger question at hand is how all strategic resources work. Is a mine required for any strategic resource or does it depend on the resource?

Comment: Different resources(luxury or strategic) need different improvements. i.e. To gain sheep you'll need to put a camp on that tile. To get oil you'll need to build an oil rig. When your worker is on the tile that has a resource it'll usually recommend the improvement for you.

Comment: Thanks. When I get back to my game I'll give this a try. Although, I must note (for others) that I never got the prompt or suggestion to build a mine on my Niter deposit...

Comment: @FrankV If you already have an improvement there it won't suggest the new one. You'll have to manually remove it.